# ID or Class tag inside div tag

Tags: html, css

Guyz i m completely new on css so i have this quiestions.....

```css
h1 {
  color: red
}
p{
  color: blue
}
#ftx {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<h1>It appears fine red</h1>
<p>Pretty good appears blue</p>
<div id="ftx">
<h1> why doesn't it appears green?</h1>
<p/>Neither it appears green</p>
</div>
```

Why doesn't the div tag inherit h1 and p?

why doesn't the ftx id inherit the h1 and p tag inside the div tag?

Comment: `<p/>Neither it appears green</p>` You have a typo in your opening tag, it is supposed to be `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

The style indicated **does** apply to the text in the div *unless* it is overriden by other styles.

In the snippet below, you can see that the `span` is green because no other styling has been applied.

That is not the case for the `h1` and `p` whether the existing styles apply because they have not been overridden.

```css
h1 {
  color: red
}
p {
  color: blue
}
#ftx {
  color: green
}
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<h1>It appears fine red</h1>
<p>Pretty good appears blue</p>
<div id="ftx">
  <h1> why doesn't it appears green?</h1>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span>
  <p>Neither it appears green</p>
</div>
```